# Keep the delimiter at third position and rest of other split

Tags: java

I am trying to split , (Comma) delimiter file where I need to skip , (Comma) at position three and rest of , (Comma) I can split.

**My code:**

```
    String st;

            BufferedReader Br = null;
            FileOutputStream outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\DATA\\data.xls"));
            Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
            File objFile = new File(
                    "C:\\DATA\\user.txt");

            Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));

            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
            Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("UserData");

            System.out.println("Total Rows in the File : " +lines);

            int line = 0;

            while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {

                String value = st.replace("\"", "");

                arraylist = value.split(",");

                Row row = null;

                Cell cell = null;

                row = sheet.createRow(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {

                    // System.out.println(arraylist[i]);

                    cell = row.createCell(i);

                    cell.setCellValue(arraylist[i]);

                }

                line++;

//              System.out.println("Line: " + line);

            }
            book.write(outFile1);
            outFile1.close();

            Br.close();
```

**How my txt file look:**

```
"userid","Subscriberid ","HeadhouseFullname",
"167fgfg611","5904fds02","ABC, XYZ C"
"200fhskdhf","876fsgj25","ACD, NNP C"
"3893fjs956","502sgfgg3","ADC, KIO C"
"918shdfd71","1029gsg57","AED, JUI C"
```

**Currently, when the code has been executed then it prints this file value:**

```
        userid    Subscriberid HeadhouseFullname
        167fgfg611 5904fds02 ABC XYZ C
        200fhskdhf 876fsgj25 ACD NNP C
        3893fjs956 502sgfgg3 ADC KIO C
        918shdfd71 1029gsg57 AED JUI C
```

**How it should be printed:**

```
    userid    Subscriberid HeadhouseFullname
    167fgfg611 5904fds02 ABC, XYZ C
    200fhskdhf 876fsgj25 ACD, NNP C
    3893fjs956 502sgfgg3 ADC, KIO C
    918shdfd71 1029gsg57 AED, JUI C
```

Where you can notice that `HeadhouseFullname` column value is full name. For example `"ABC, XYZ C"` where I don't want to split full name by , (Comma) delimiter throughout the file. I want to keep it as it is `"ABC, XYZ C"`.
Currently, it's splitting wherever it see , (Comma) delimiter.

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV parsing library, like [the one in Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)? That will handle the quoting properly, as well as the large number of CSV dialects, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should be using a CSV lib as commented above, but if you want to keep going down your current path, try updating your split logic to be:

```
            while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) { 
                arraylist = st.split(",");
                Row row = null;
                Cell cell = null;
                row = sheet.createRow(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {
                     // System.out.println(arraylist[i]);
                       cell = row.createCell(i);
                       cell.setCellValue(arraylist[i].replace("\"", ""));
                 }

                line++;
                //System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            }
```

Comment: This is not helping as it is just replacing " quote later when it is actually setting values in the cell but then it is printing same as before. No change.

Comment: It's not JUST replacing the quote.  It's splitting the values differently

Answer (score 0):

You could start splitting the line on `"` characters, i.e. `st.split("\"")`. At this point, the resulting array would contain your entries of interest plus two additional kind of strings: empty and `,` character only.

```
String[] values = str.split("\"");
```

Once done that, you could iterate over the resulting array only considering and processing your entries as follows:

```
for (int valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < values.length; valueIndex++) {
    if (values[valueIndex].length() > 0 && !values[valueIndex].equals(",")) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH values[valueIndex]...
    }
}
```

So, considering the source code you posted, the while loop would change as follows:

```
while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = st.split("\"");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(line++);
    for (int valueIndex = 0, cellIndex = 0; valueIndex < values.length; valueIndex++) {
        if (values[valueIndex].length() > 0 && !values[valueIndex].equals(",")) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex++);
            cell.setCellValue(values[valueIndex]);
        }    
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

I added one additional loop with following updated code and now third column is populating combine with First name, last name and middle initial:

Here below is my updated code:

```
String st;                      

            BufferedReader Br = null;
            FileOutputStream outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\DATA\\data.xls"));
            Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
            File objFile = new File(
                    "C:\\DATA\\user.txt");

            Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));

            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
            Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("UserData");

            System.out.println("Total Rows in the File : " +lines);

            int line = 0;

            while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {

                arraylist = st.split("," + "\"");

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {
                    arraylist[i] = arraylist[i].replace("\"", "");
                }

                Row row = null;

                Cell cell = null;

                row = sheet.createRow(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {

//                   System.out.println(arraylist[i]);

                    cell = row.createCell(i);

                    cell.setCellValue(arraylist[i]);

                }

                line++;

//              System.out.println("Line: " + line);

            }
            book.write(outFile1);
            outFile1.close();

            Br.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried using regex and it helped for example

String txt = "0, 2, 23131312,\"This, is a message\", 1212312"; System.out.println(Arrays.toString(txt.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")));